# Explain $E=\frac{1}{2}\left(E+\frac{2}{3}\right).$

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, expected-value

> Question: Roll a fair dice until the game stops. The game stops when you get a 4, 5, or 6. For every 1, 2, or 3 your score increases by +1. If the game stops with a 4 or 5, you get paid the accumulated score. If the game stops with a 6 you get nothing. What is the expected payoff of this game?

I encounter this question from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/915541/contradictory-recursion).
Answer is $\frac{2}{3}.$

While reading André Nicolas's solution at that post, I do not understand one step.

> Let $E$ be the expected score. We condition on the result of the first toss. If that toss is $4$, $5$, or $6$, then the amount we get, and therefore the expectation, is $0$.
>
> Given that the first toss is  a $1$, $2$, or $3$,  our expectation is **not** $E+1$. For the $1$ is not a sure thing. With probability $\frac{1}{3}$ it will not be credited to you, because the game will end with a $6$. It follows that
> $$E=\frac{1}{2}\left(E+\frac{2}{3}\right).$$
> That yields $E=\frac{2}{3}$.

I do not understand why would we obtain the $\frac{2}{3}$ in the equation
$$E=\frac{1}{2}\left(E+\frac{2}{3}\right).$$

Is it due to the law of total expectation?

Comment: Didn't he just solved that equation?

Comment: Yes, but I do not understand how to obtain the $\frac{2}{3}$ in the equation $E = \frac{1}{2}\left( E + \frac{2}{3} \right).$ Perhaps you can explain?

Comment: Do you mean the $2/3$ in the brackets or $2/3$ as a solution?

Comment: Yes. Why is it $E + \frac{2}{3}?$

Comment: I see. Sorry, I thought that you were unsure about the $2/3$ as a solution of the equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With probability $1/2$, you get nothing (because your first roll is a $4$, $5$, or $6$).

The rest of the time, also with probability $1/2$, you get something, which we'll call $F$.  Your score from the second roll on is also $E$, because it is essentially the game starting from scratch.  However, $F$ equals $E$ plus whatever you keep of the $1$ point you earned from the first roll.  When the game ends with a $6$ (with probability $1/3$), you don't get to keep any of that $1$ point; however, when the game ends with a $4$ or $5$ (with probability $2/3$), you get to keep that $1$ point.  On average, then, you get to keep $2/3$ of that point.

So $F = E + 2/3$, and your overall expectation is $F/2 = (E+2/3)/2$.  By equating this with $E$, the expectation from the beginning of the game, we get $E = 2/3$.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Is it possible to be more mathematically rigorous? For example, when the game ends with a $4$ or $5$, why is probability is $\frac{2}{3}?$

Comment: Because the game can only end with three possible values: $4$, $5$, or $6$, each equally likely.  Two-thirds of those values leave you with the full value of your initial point; one-third leaves you with nothing.  Hence, the average value of that initial point is $2/3 \times 1 + 1/3 \times 0 = 2/3$.

Comment: I see how to get the $\frac{2}{3}$ now. But why do we take the average?

Comment: That's what "expected value" means—it means "average."  The wording may seem to imply something like "most likely value," but that's not what it means.

Comment: I know the meaning of expected value. Is it possible to prove $F = E + \frac{2}{3}$ using the law of total expectation?

Comment: Sure.  Let's use $V$ for the value of the game, to avoid confusion in notation.  Then $E(V) = E(V \mid 4, 5) P(4, 5) + E(V \mid 6) P(6) = [E(V)+1](2/3) + [E(V)](1/3) = E(V) + 2/3$.

Comment: Why don't we have $E(V|1), E(V|2)$ and $E(V|3)?$

Comment: @Idonknow: Because the game never ends on a $1$, $2$, or $3$.  I'm using $E(V \mid 4, 5)$ as shorthand for $E(V \mid \text{game ends on a $4$ or $5$})$, and likewise for $E(V \mid 6)$.

Comment: I thought that the equation $E(V) = E(V|4,5)P(4,5) + E(V|6)P(6)$ is due to the law of total expectation? If this is the case, I think we should include $E(V|i)P(i)$ for $i=1,2,3.$

Comment: @Idonknow: Sure, but $P(1) = P(2) = P(3) = 0$.  The game never ends with a 1, 2, or 3!

Comment: May I know how you define $P(1)?$

Comment: @Idonknow: $P(1) \stackrel{\text{def}}{=} P(\text{the game ends with a roll of $1$})$.  It is, of course, equal to zero.  ETA: I'm pretty sure any elaboration I continue with is going to confuse you.  Somehow I'm unable to convey to you this answer.  Perhaps someone else will provide an answer.

Comment: Ah, now I see. I understand your solution now.

Comment: Good, I'm glad to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Either you get to roll (with P = 3/6) or you dont.
In case you do, you'll earn E more with

1. P = 3/6 of earning 1 more (rolling 1 or 2 or 3)
2. P = 2/6 of earning 0 (rolling 4 or 5)
3. P = 1/6 of losing 1 (rolling a 6)

$$E = \frac36 \cdot \left( E + \frac36(1) + \frac26(0) + \frac16(-1) \right) +  \frac36 \cdot (0)$$